# Image is not showing in the web page even though it is opened separately

Tags: html, image, vue.js

I have several images from an external web site such as this : http://static.wikia.nocookie.net/mightandmagic/images/8/8e/Urgashtcm1962285.png/revision/latest?cb=20150307173959&path-prefix=en

I can access it when I open it in a separate tab but when I want to load it into my webpage with *<img src='http://static.wikia.nocookie.net/mightandmagic/images/8/8e/Urgashtcm1962285.png/revision/latest?cb=20150307173959&path-prefix=en'/*> it gives 404 not found error. What might be the cause of that?

Here is the vue html code :

```
<img v-bind:src="e.smallImage"
              @mouseover="mouseOver($event,e)" @mouseleave="mouseLeave($event,e)">
```

And here is the html code in the rendered page :

```
<div id="48807" class="entity">
<a href="#">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://static.wikia.nocookie.net/mightandmagic/images/8/8e/Urgashtcm1962285.png/revision/latest?cb=20150307173959&amp;path-prefix=en" style="display: inline-block; width: 179.391px; height: 103.266px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;">
        <figcaption>Urgash (M&amp;M)</figcaption>
    </figure>
</a>
</div>
```

Also, there are other images from different sources including my local computer and other web sites but they are shown. Here is one of them : https://i.ibb.co/XYzswZC/Hogwartscrest.png

EDIT : I solved it by adding *referrerPolicy* attribute to the img element as described in my answer BUT it only works correctly when I hard reload the page. If I normally reload the page when I check the network tab in the developer tools I see that it again makes request with Referrer-Policy : strict-origin-when-cross-origin and it ignores my referrerPolicy attribute in the img element. Is there a way to make it send with no-referrer policy in the every page load?

Comment: Please add more details like html and css in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The cause of this is usually SSL. If your site is served over https and you are loading external images over http they might not show. Check the developers tool set for your browser and you should see the error there.

Comment: I edited the question. I both tried the url of image I want to show with http and https, both gives 404 error. How can I see developers tool set on Chrome?

Comment: To see the developers tools on chrome just open the page, right click and open "inspect". Them browse to the different logs to check for errors, "Console should be the right one. You may have to reload the page though.
Sorry I just realised you solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

So, it's because the img is requested with header "Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin" and this returns 404 because of cors security I added *referrerPolicy="no-referrer"* to my img element and it got resolved.

EDIT: It resulted with a situation where the images loaded at the intial load without caching, and don't get loaded in the following loads. I solved it by adding *crossorigin="anonymous"* attribute to my img element.